# MongoDB query returns 3 dots instead of answer

Tags: mongodb-query

I am following an online course on a website and when I am trying to submit a query on my local MongoDB, it returns `...` instead of the answer.

The query I submit is

`db.scores.find( { "type" : "essay", "score" : 50 }, { student : true, _id : false ).pretty()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `"..."` that I get as an "answer" from the local MongoDB server indicates that the server is expecting from me to provide it with more input.

I clearly have a syntax error on my query, I forgot to close a curly bracket.

The correct query `db.scores.find( { "type" : "essay", "score" : 50 }, { student : true, _id : false } ).pretty()` does not return `"..."`

HINT: In case the forgotten input is not in the end of the query, but somewhere in the middle (as happened in this query) you can escape the `"..."` mode by hitting the "enter" two times and then try to type in the new query again.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful. I don't however get the point of them returning ... when you cannot actually edit the initial command to fix the query. Instead you will just have to enter "Enter" twice, which feels counterintuitive.

Answer (score 4):

When I had this same error, its was the result of a string value being terminated prematurely due to a ' or " in the string. Look for any extraneous quotation marks or apostrophes in the values you're adding which may interfere with the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just as addition: watch out the password string. Be aware it not to contain quotation mark which interfers with quotation mark of declaration of it, like in my case. I got ... too.